# Откуда пошло выражение "олух царя небесного"?

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "Олух царя небесного" и что оно значило изначально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот версия Грамоты.ру

*Олух царя небесного (прост. неодобр.) – глупый человек, простофиля. Слово олух имеет в народных говорах целый ряд однокоренных слов: волух, валух, валуй, валях (со значениями: лентяй, увалень, дурак, бездельник). Все эти существительные – производные глагола валяться, почти все они обозначают и бездельника, и глупца (хотя есть гипотезы, которые возводят слово олух к другим языкам, в т. ч. финскому и арабскому). Первоначальным значением слова олух было 'лодырь, лежебока', затем оно развивает и значение 'глупый'. На фоне народных синонимов, таких как пень божий, выражение расшифровывается достаточно легко. Известно, что юродивые, шуты, нищие и блаженные пользовались особой милостью Бога (небесного царя). Олух царя небесного, следовательно, – это один из таких бездельников, глупцов, который ждет милости от небесного царя.*

Я бы только уточнил, что в этом ключе речь может идти не только о бездельнике, но скорее юродивом, "божьем человеке", проводнике божьего промысла (чтобы не сказать "пророке"), который отнюдь не ждёт милости божьей, иной чем вдохновение или провидение.

Массу других версий вам даст любой поисковик.

Answer (score 1):

Происхождение слова <<**ОЛУХ**>> конкретно объясняет "**Полный церковно-славянский словарь**" магистра Гр. Дьяченко (который , почему-то , ленятся листать языковеды  ) . Откроем его на *стр.92* и увидим там слово <<**ВОЛОУХЪ**>> в значении **коровий , бычий пастух** , с пояснением , *что от этого слова произошло современное* <<**ОЛУХ**>> , - интернет.ссылка - [ПЦСС стр.92](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0092.htm) . Весь фразеологизм <<**ОЛУХ ЦАРЯ НЕБЕСНОГО**>> можно бы понять так , что в пастухи во время оно попадали те , кто не годился для сколько-нибудь более серьёзной работы . Насколько я знаю , на Руси почётным считался труд земледельца , а работа со скотиной расценивалась , как непрестижная . Однако , мне кажется , магистр Гр. Дьяченко несколько поверхностен в толковании "*олуха*" . Обратим внимание , что на этой же странице тут же , перед <<**ВОЛОУХЪ**>> им помещено и слово <<**ВОЛУЙ**>> в значениях **воловий бычий** и **кнут , бич** . Если бы вместо (**В**)**ОЛУХ** было (**В**)**ОЛУЙ** , то цельныйфразеологизм   <<**ОЛУХ ЦАРЯ НЕБЕСНОГО**>> легко и логично истолковывался , как синоним другого фразеологизма - <<**БИЧ БОЖИЙ**>> или <<**НАКАЗАНИЕ ГОСПОДНЕ**>> ; в сущности , практическое упоминание *олуха царя небесного* именно такому значению и соответствует - этакое разъэтакое наказание , выражающееся в природной глупости того , кто *олухом царя небесного* и назван . Мне думается , тут присутствует смешение этих  двух древнерусских слов , - <<**ВОЛОУХ**>> и <<**ВОЛУЙ**>> , и с проглатыванием буквы **О** , - по типу украинско-русских пар : укр. ВОНА - русск. ОНА , укр. ВIКНО - русск. ОКНО , укр. ВОГОНЬ - русск. ОГОНЬ , укр. ВУЛИЦА - русск. УЛИЦА и др.т.п. .  ===========================================================================  [image: ОЛУХ скриншот ПЦСС]

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что пропущена буква "с", и тогда получается = ослух царя небесного.
То есть человек не следует законам Божьим или без царя в голове.Тогда все
становится на свои места в этом выражении.

Comment: Как бич Божий,или кнут не соответствует употребительному значению.Олух=это разгильдяй,бесполезный,неорганизованный человек,не способный выполнять поручения.Ослух =это более точное соответствие значению в речевой практике.

Comment: А ваша версия хоть чем-то подкрепляется, кроме собственно вашего  мнения?  Вообще идея объяснять что-то ошибками, опечатками и прочим крайне непродуктивна.